# <|> in Parsec - why do these examples behave differently?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I think I'm misunderstanding `<|>` in parsec - I have an input stream that contains either a bunch of `a`s in one representation or a bunch of `a`s in another representation. I would expect the following to functions to be equivalent (given that the input is the form I said, and I have verified that it is):

```
foo = do
    ...
    a1s <- many $ try $ a1
    a2s <- many $ try $ a2
    return $ a1s ++ a2s
```

versus

```
foo = do
    ...
    as <- (many $ try $ a1) <|> (many $ try $ a2)
    return as
```

What could be going wrong? The first function works on my input, the second function fails, saying unexpected a2, expecting a1.

Comment: In the first example, it does `many $ try $ a1`, then does `many $ try $ a2`, both always execute.  In the second, it does `many $ try $ a1`, then if that fails it executes `many $ try $ a2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give a sequence of a2 to the latter parser, the first `many` matches and returns an empty list, so it doesn't try to match against the second `many`.

You can use `many1` instead.

```
foo = do
    ...
    as <- many1 a1 <|> many a2
    return as
```

In this case, the `many1` fails when you give a sequence of a2, and the `many` matches against the input.